# the picture in the first row of the table displayed, while the rest of the pictures are not displayed PHP

Tags: php

I create a table that contain of cat information. In that cat information, there are picture, name, age, gender, and description that I have to display in the table. The problem is, only the picture in the first row of the table displayed, while the rest are not displayed. The name, age, gender and description have no problem in displaying the data in the table. I have to display 10 cats information in the table.
Here is the code

```
 <?php

include("include/connection.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM cat";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

?>

    <form action="add_cat.php"><div align="right"><button class="btn btn-success mb-2">Add New Cat</button></div></form>
                <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
                    <table class="table border border-dark" width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                        <thead class="thead-secondary">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Num</th>
                                <th scope="col">Cat ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Picture</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Age</th>
                                <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <!-- fetched data from cat table -->
                        <?php 
                        $num =1;
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $num; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['id_cat']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo "<img src= '", $row['picture'] ,"' width='175' height='100' />" ?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="edit_cat.php"><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></a>
                                    <a href="delete_cat.php?id_cat=<?php echo $row['id_cat']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $num++;
                            } ?>  
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: already updated.

Comment: What does the generated source come out as? This looks valid so likely is a client side issue.

Comment: Based on previous question(s) I think `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES['picture']['name'])` could be your issue. Parameter 2 should be where the file is going to be stored, `$_FILES['picture']['name']` is a name, not location... this is a guess though.. not enough info still.

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo in your syntax. Periods concatenate strings in PHP. It should be:

`<?php echo "<img src= '". $row['picture'] ."' width='175' height='100' />" ?>`

Comment: there is no syntax error

Comment: Commas work for `echo`s. https://3v4l.org/DDqIU

Comment: i still cant get it

Comment: Crazy, I never knew that. I stand corrected :)

Comment: (I prefer concatenating but its not the issue for this one. `echo is not a function but a language construct. Its arguments are a list of expressions following the echo keyword, separated by commas`)